# How to get property description of a typedef correctly displayed by WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

Here is my javascript code which uses some JSDoc typedef :

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} BuildOptions
 * @property {string} tag - Name of build tag
 */

/**
 * @param {BuildOptions} options
 */
Builder.prototype.build = function(options) {
    // ...
}
```

In my `build` function, when I type `options.t` and ask for completion, WebStorm (8.0.4) correctly suggests me the `tag` property but doesn't show `Name of build tag` as a description of the property.

Does somebody knows how to correctly write JSDoc typedef property's description for WebStorm to display it correctly?

Comment: Looking around the forums, I don't think WebStorm currently supports this. [You should file a feature request](http://www.jetbrains.com/devnet/index.jsp) because I would love to have this.